# Opening an sql connection as soon as execute gets called

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Consider the following function which returns an sql command with closed connection

```
public static SqlCommand CreateTableCommand(this IList<Columns> Columns,string connectionString=null)
{
   //.
   //.
   //.
   var command = new SqlCommand(query.ToString());
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tablename",T.Name);
   command.Connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString??App.db.GetConnectionString());
   return command;
}
```

i use it as the following

```
someObject.GetColumns().ToList().CreateTableCommand().ExecuteNonQuery();
```

is there a way to open the connection automatically slightly before an `ExecuteNonQuery()` or `ExecuteScalar()` is called? i dont want to return an open connection because i might not call execute instantly

Comment: Seems like a bit of an anti-pattern. You should look into why the connection would be closed in the first place and write a wrapper for that.

Comment: @RGraham i think writing an extention method to sql command that opens the connection and calls ExecuteNonQuery() or any other Execute is a good option, but i asked to make sure if its possible to specify the behaviour without writing another function

Comment: Who would close the connection?

Comment: @RGraham the SqlCommand can close the connection because he knows which connection he used

Comment: @RGraham the extention method itself somthing like public static object SqlCommand(this SqlCommand  command,enum commandtype) and switch case to chose between ExecuteNonQuery() or ExecuteScalar() execute reader for some other functions

Comment: It's absolutely *possible*. I wanted to just highlight the fact that, in my opinion, this violates SRP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could write an extension

```
    public static int MyExecuteNonQuery(this SqlCommand command)
    {
        command.Connection.Open();
        var buff = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        command.Connection.Close();

        return buff;
    }
```